# How to add debian "testing" repository to apt-get

Tags: debian, apt

I had difficulty searching for this answer on google and debian documentation!

The FAQ page wasnt very clear either. I mean it wasnt 100% idiot-proof clear.
https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting

Comment: If you want idiot-proof, don't use testing repos!

Comment: It's as idiot proof as Googling is. Considering this question dates back to the origins of modern Debian it has been asked pretty frequently. [A quick](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-choosing.en.html‎) [Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915232/debian-sources-list-for-testing-what-to-change) [search](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/upgrading-debian-to-unstable) [gives](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=810742) [the](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=84543) [answer](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-debian-squeeze-to-wheezy)

Comment: You had difficulty finding it in the Debian documentation because you are not supposed to do it.

Comment: @MichaelPobega: The fact that the question has been asked frequently automatically implies that the FAQ page is grossly insufficient for such a simple operation. I took some time to find the answer online so I posted the answer myself.

Answer (score 16):

"testing" repo makes new updated packages available to the user (ie `apt-get` or `synaptic`) which would otherwise come in the next `Debian` release.

*Caution: testing packages may not be the most stable packages, but it is more stable than the "unstable" repo.*

1. Login as root Open file `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your favourite
   editor

   `vi /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Adding the testing repo. Add the below line.

   `deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ testing non-free contrib main`
3. Then run `sudo apt-get update`

**MISC NOTES:**

Note the format of the repo line added.

`deb <link from where packages will be downloaded from> <repoName> <sub branches of the repo>`

Examples:

`deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ testing non-free contrib main` 
`deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ stable non-free contrib main` 
`deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable non-free contrib main` 
`deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy non-free contrib main`

Note in the above line "wheezy" repo is debian 7.0 release default repo.
Unstable repo can have error prone packages.

Comment: Forgive me if there are mistakes and please correct them if possible. Thanks.

Comment: This is such a horrible idea, and is a big Debian No-No, but it *is* a good answer to the question.